# Customizing the Calendar View in SP 2010

Tags: calendar

I am very new to sharepoint and so is the organization I work for. Our IT group has created a Sharepoint calendar which I have subsequently embedded in our website (external to sharepoint).  The calendar takes up a lot of real-estate on our web page and I am wondering if it can be customized to remove the left-hand column that displays the mini calendar of months and also Saturday and Sunday. Right now, our parents have to scroll around to see the entire calendar. Additionally, the calendar is not viewable from mobile phones.  On ipad, you can view the calendar, but cannot open any events to view details.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you!  Kat